# Spring Data JPA inserting underline character between variable words

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Spring Data JPA inserts underscore character between words in variables, that does not happen if second term is not an word:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table")
public class Entity{
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String variableA;
private String variableYes;
}
```

For 'variableA' it creates table with variableA SQL text insertion, for 'variableYes' it inserts in SQL variable_Yes, I didn't found documentation for this particularity. Eclipse IDE console:

```
create table questao (id bigint not null, variableA char(255), variable_Yes varchar(255), primary key (id));
```

Answer (score 0):

CamelCase is used by default. When encountering a capital letter (not last and next letter in lower case) When is considered the beginning of a new word.  You can try `variableAA` and `variableAa`, which generate `variableaa` and `variable_aa`. It's good practice to explicitly specify a name using `@Column(name = "variable_a")`.

Answer (score 0):

hibernate allow you define strategy. see:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#PhysicalNamingStrategy

You can define custom implementations of this PhysicalNamingStrategy. if you don't, i guess it use **SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy** as default strategy.

In **SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy**, it generate column name by property name use the below method:

```
private boolean isUnderscoreRequired(char before, char current, char after) {
        return Character.isLowerCase(before) && Character.isUpperCase(current) && Character.isLowerCase(after);
    }
```

So, variableA is not match the rule, but variableYes match. And you database is casesensitive, so variableYes convert to variable_Yes, but variableA nothing changed.